# meteor -p 80 --production force to points to https://localhost

Tags: testing, meteor, production

I've been trying to get a production feel of the "todos" sample of meteor. In the terminal I issued to following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/meteor/todos
$ cd todos
```

I initially got some errors to some dependency so I installed them

```
$ meteor npm install --save faker
$ npm install autoprefixer
```

Then I executed

```
$ meteor -p 80 --production
```

This is what I got in the terminal after that.

```
root@b:vbox1~/meteor/todos# meteor -p 80 --production
[[[[[ ~/meteor/todos ]]]]]                    

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Meteor 1.3.1 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:80/
```

But when I tried accessing using the server's http://192.168.1.4 (Server IP) in the browser, it keeps me forwarded to https://localhost.

Is it possible to have a production feel using the server's IP?

TIA

Comment: did you install the force ssl package that it's redirecting to https?

Comment: Set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable to `https://192.168.1.4:80`.

Comment: Actually I just installed meteor as it is. Not sure if it has force SSL package.